# Need to validate image height and width validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a jQuery code snippet to handle image uploads and wish to perform validation based on specific image dimensions.

My current code includes functionality for uploading images, but I need to validate whether the uploaded images have the dimensions of 1000 pixels in width and 1250 pixels in height.

Furthermore, if the dimensions do not match, I want to remove the preview of the invalid image.

Here's the jQuery code I'm currently using:

```
$("#thumbnail").spartanMultiImagePicker({
    fieldName: 'image',
    maxCount: 1,
    rowHeight: 'auto',
    groupClassName: 'col-12',
    maxFileSize: '',
    placeholderImage: {
        image: '{{ asset('assets/back-end/img/400x400/img2.jpg') }}',
        width: '100%',
    },
    dropFileLabel: "Drop Here",
    onAddRow: function(index, file) {

    },
    onRenderedPreview: function(index) {

    },
    onRemoveRow: function(index) {

    },
    onExtensionErr: function(index, file) {
        toastr.error(
        '{{ \App\CPU\translate('Please only input png or jpg type file') }}', {
            CloseButton: true,
            ProgressBar: true
        });
    },
    onSizeErr: function(index, file) {
        toastr.error('{{ \App\CPU\translate('File size too big') }}', {
            CloseButton: true,
            ProgressBar: true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check dimensions in this way.

```
    onRenderedPreview: function(index) {
        var image = $("#thumbnail").find(".spartan_image_input")[index];
        if (image) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                // Check dimensions
                if (this.width !== 1000 || this.height !== 1250) {
                    // Remove the preview and show an error message
                    toastr.error('The image dimensions must be 1000x1250 pixels.', {
                        CloseButton: true,
                        ProgressBar: true
                    });

                    // Removal function
                    $("#thumbnail").spartanMultiImagePicker('removeRow', index);
                }
            };
            img.src = $(image).val();
        }
    },
```